# How to compare the signature of two functions?

Tags: c++, function, c++17, std, function-signature

Is there a way to check if two functions have the same signature? For example:

```
int funA (int a, int b);
int funB (int a, int b);
float funC (int a, int b);
int funD (float a, int b);
```

In this example, `funA` and `funB` is the only combination of functions that should return `true`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Essentially you want to check if types of two functions are the same:

`std::is_same_v<decltype(funA), decltype(funB)>`

I wouldn't call this 'comparing signatures', as, if I remember correctly, return type is not a part of a signature (because it doesn't affect overload resolution).

Comment: A return type does participate in overload resolution for function *pointers*, and it is part of the signature for function *templates*.

Answer (score 15):

You can check the function type with [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) and [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same). e.g.

```
std::is_same_v<decltype(funA), decltype(funB)>  // true
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SoAWClqlfzmCoi8Y)

Answer (score 14):

Others have mentioned the solution using `std::is_same` and `decltype`.

Now to generalize the comparison for an arbitrary number of function signatures, you can do the following

```
#include <type_traits> // std::is_same, std::conjunction_v

template<typename Func, typename... Funcs>
constexpr bool areSameFunctions = std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<Func, Funcs>...>;
```

and compare as many functions as one like

```
areSameFunctions<decltype(funA), decltype(funB), decltype(funC)>
```

**([See Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GiHQo9jRYql3iHSp))**

---

Or for less typing (i.e. without `decltype`), make it as a function

```
template<typename Func, typename... Funcs>
constexpr bool areSameFunctions(Func&&, Funcs&&...)
{
   return std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<Func, Funcs>...>;
}
```

and call simply by

```
areSameFunctions(funA, funB, funC)
```

**([See Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vnQhYZR7cz4SXVoY))**

Answer (score 3):

As another possibility that hasn't been mentioned: you can use `typeid` from `typeinfo` and `==`:

```
#include <typeinfo>

if(typeid(funA) != typeid(funB))
    std::cerr << "Types not the same" << std::endl;
```

Comment: GCC gives me `error: non-constant condition for static assertion`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ah, this is RTTI. Didn't know that these weren't `constexpr`. I have a slightly better example now.